# How to add Android Notificaton additional instructions?

Tags: android

I try a notification example.

How to add additional instructions like this image

[image]

My notification code

```
NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("New Message with implicit intent")
        .setContentText("New message from javacodegeeks received...")
        .setTicker("Implicit: New Message Received!")
        .setSmallIcon(MainActivity.NotiImage)
        .setAutoCancel( false )
        .setNumber( ++NotificationHelper.messagges )
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), MainActivity.NotiImage ));

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        String[] events = new String[3];
        events[0] = new String("1) Message for implicit intent");
        events[1] = new String("2) big view Notification");
        events[2] = new String("3) from javacodegeeks!");

        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("More Details:");
        for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
            inboxStyle.addLine("olkun " + i);
        }
        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        myNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.setSummaryText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html#setSummaryText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
inboxStyle.setSummaryText("Summary Text goes here");
```

Also described in the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify) as:

> **Summary text**
>
> Allows you to add a line of text below the details area.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `setSubText()` is the [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSubText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to use " Big picture style " like this

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
.setContentTitle("Event tracker")
.setContentText("Events received")
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
    new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
String[] events = new String[6];
// Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");
...
// Moves events into the big view
for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
}
// Moves the big view style object into the notification object.
mBuilder.setStyle(inBoxStyle);
...
// Issue the notification here.
```

Write the updates you want in the events array